# Fix the type casting in Java calcuator application

Tags: java, casting, double, calculator

im trying to design a calculator app the way it should work, unlike the conventional ones that ask for first number and second number, then the operator. i have designed mine to take input from the user as typed and then process. My problem is if i want to perform a division such that either operator is a float/double how do i set the initial type of the variables and once input different from the initial type how do i change the type to accommodate new variable

```
static int initVal = 0;
static int finalVal = 0;
..
..
..

            work.screen.setText(work.screen.getText() );
            String keyPressed = Integer.toString(initVal);
            initVal = Integer.parseInt(keyPressed);
```

On the interface, if I keypress numbers that includes a decimal place or my answer is a decimal place it doesnt type cast correctly. I have tried making everything Double instead of integer but then if i keypress numbers without decimal place it becomes converted into fractions. confused.

a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: The question would be much better readable if you removed unnecessary code and leave here only the parts relevant for your question. Maybe by doing this you will even be able to answer your own question :)

Comment: the entire code has to be provided in case interested exchanger want to run it to understand the operation of the application. summary is that im unable to make successful switch between integer input/result and double input/result.

Comment: Don't say we really need to see all your buttons, all your arithmetical operations etc. Only 2 examples would be enough. Other things in a similar way.

Comment: thanks for this, as you can see this is my first post on SO, new here. is it ok to clear out the codes now and leave out the area i felt i needed the attention? the doubt of mistakenly leaving out a key part what what made me upload it all

Comment: Feel free to edit and improve your original post! It should stay in the SO knowledge base for others so the better it us, the more useful. Ideally there should be *just* the relevant code - not more, not less 

Comment: Done that, i hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `finalVal` and `initVal` doubles instead of ints. This way they can have decimal values. Then instead of using `Integer.parseInt()` you can use `Double.parseDouble()`

Comment: i have tried this before, but instead it converts normal numbers without decimal values into something else. A keypress of 2 will result in .02 during computation.

Comment: @Bit Bender then you probably have bug somewhere else. Only problems you should encounter are that `2+2=4.0` istead of `2+2=4` (looks ugly on output) and much worse, problems caused by precision lost.

Comment: are you suggesting i convert all input to double before performing calculations on them? maybe i was doing it wrongly but when i did it a keypress of 2 becomes 0.02 on the screen during computation